# Cantidad de años de una fecha inicial y una fecha final no me trae números decimales

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, programación-funcional

resulta que capturo 2 fechas , y en una variable decimal que llame Antiguedad_en_Anios llevo a cabo una operación que me obtiene la cantidad de años, pero resulta que necesito que me arroje un valor decimal por decir 9,52 años, y siempre me arroja un valor preciso, por ejemplo 9 años cerrados.Como hago para que el resultado me traiga los decimales. Muchas Gracias

Acontinuación les muestro como lo estoy haciendo (Una fecha que se obtiene de un componente de windows forms, y otra fecha que la traigo de una base de datos)

```
TimeSpan DiasAntiguedad= (dateFecCorte.Value.Date - Antiguedad);
Antiguedad_en_Anios = (DiasAntiguedad.Days * 1) / 360;
```

Comment: o si existe otra forma para obtener la cantidad de años entre 2 fechas, agradecería mucho que me la dieran a conocer , muchas gracias

Comment: de que tipo son todas esas variables?

Answer (score 3):

En C# (y otros muchos lenguajes), el resultado de dividir 2 numeros enteros da como resultado otro numero entero.

En tu caso, divides `DiasAntiguedad.Days` que es de tipo `Int32`, por `360` que tambien es `Int32`, por eso el resultado no te da decimales.

La solución es simplemente convertir cualquiera de los dos valores a `double` o `decimal`:

```
Antiguedad_en_Anios = DiasAntiguedad.Days / 360.0;
```

o

```
Antiguedad_en_Anios = (double)DiasAntiguedad.Days / 360;
```

Debes tener en cuenta que `Antiguedad_en_Anios` debe ser de tipo `double` para poder almacenar valores de este tipo.